# Simple custom javascript scroller

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, scroller

I need to list some titles. Only 6 of them should be visible at one time. 
I'm not allowed to use any external library. 
Everything works fine except if I click `down` to scroll list down and than click `up`, the list scrolls up only after the second click.

I understand that the problem is in my global variables that holds list positions and functions, but I can't understand why do they get updated only after second click, not the first one!

Would appreciate your help and please consider that I'm only learning JS at the moment.

html part

```
       <div class="mailOptions">
        <div class="incProducts">
          <h3>Include Products</h3>
          <div class="moveOptUp"><span>UP</span></div>
          <nav class="allMailOptions">
            <div class="mailOpt" id="mailOpt_1">
              <span class="optWithMarks"></span>
              <span class="mailOptName">1 abcdefg</span>
              <span class="optMarked"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="mailOpt" id="mailOpt_2">
              <span class="optWithMarks"></span>
              <span class="mailOptName">2 abcdefg</span>
              <span class="optMarked"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="mailOpt" id="mailOpt_3">
              <span class="optWithMarks"></span>
              <span class="mailOptName">3 abcdefg</span>
              <span class="optMarked"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="mailOpt" id="mailOpt_4">
              <span class="optWithMarks"></span>
              <span class="mailOptName">4 abcdefg</span>
              <span class="optMarked"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="mailOpt" id="mailOpt_5">
              <span class="optWithMarks"></span>
              <span class="mailOptName">5 abcdefg</span>
              <span class="optMarked"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="mailOpt" id="mailOpt_6">
              <span class="optWithMarks"></span>
              <span class="mailOptName">6 abcdefg</span>
              <span class="optMarked"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="mailOpt hide" id="mailOpt_7">
              <span class="optWithMarks"></span>
              <span class="mailOptName">7 abcdefg</span>
              <span class="optMarked"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="mailOpt hide" id="mailOpt_8">
              <span class="optWithMarks"></span>
              <span class="mailOptName">8 abcdefg</span>
              <span class="optMarked"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="mailOpt hide" id="mailOpt_9">
              <span class="optWithMarks"></span>
              <span class="mailOptName">9 abcdefg</span>
              <span class="optMarked"></span>
            </div>
          </nav>
          <div class="moveOptDown"><span>DOWN</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

js part

```
    var targetOptTop = 1;
var targetOptDown = 7;
var targetOptLast = ($(".allMailOptions").children().length);


$('#popUpMail ').click(function(e) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //$('#popUp').removeClass('hide');
    $('.popUpEmail').addClass('show');
});

$('.cntrl-discard').click(function() {
    $('.popUpEmail').removeClass('show');
});

$('.mailOpt').click(function() {
    var id = ($(this).attr('id'));
    var idCheckBox = id.split("_");
    var idCheckBox = idCheckBox[1];

    $('.mailOpt').removeClass('activeOpt');
    $(this).addClass('activeOpt');

    $('.allIncQuotes').addClass('hide');
    $('#checkBl_' + idCheckBox).removeClass('hide');
});

function scrollMailDown(position) {
    console.log(targetOptTop);
    console.log(targetOptDown);

    if (targetOptDown < targetOptLast+1) {
        $('.mailOpt:nth-child(' + targetOptTop + ')').addClass('hide');
        $('.mailOpt:nth-child(' + targetOptDown + ')').removeClass('hide');
        targetOptTop += position;
        targetOptDown += position;
    };
};

function scrollMailUp(position) {
    console.log(targetOptTop);
    console.log(targetOptDown);

    if (targetOptTop >= 1) {
        $('.mailOpt:nth-child(' + targetOptTop + ')').removeClass('hide');
        $('.mailOpt:nth-child(' + targetOptDown + ')').addClass('hide');
        targetOptTop += position;
        targetOptDown += position;
    };
};

$('.moveOptDown').click(function() {
    scrollMailDown(+1);
});

$('.moveOptUp').click(function() {
    scrollMailUp(-1);
});
```

jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/A1ex5andr/qxHT5/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `decrement` your counters before you remove your classes like this:

```
function scrollMailUp(position) {
    console.log(targetOptTop);
    console.log(targetOptDown);
        targetOptTop--;
        targetOptDown--;
    if (targetOptTop >= 1) {

        $('.mailOpt:nth-child(' + targetOptTop + ')').removeClass('hide');
        $('.mailOpt:nth-child(' + targetOptDown + ')').addClass('hide');

    };
};
```

here is your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qxHT5/3/)

Comment: Ok, I feel stupid now )) Isn't it enough to increment and decrement each variable once when running the function after click is made?

Comment: @A1exandr: yes, in the scrollMailDown() function, you can use             'targetOptTop ++;
            targetOptDown ++;' but here after the class manipulation. So you can actually forget about your position variable, it is not needed. See in this example:http://jsfiddle.net/qxHT5/4/

Comment: problem with 
`targetOptTop--;
 targetOptDown--;` 
outside the function is that if someone click few times up (before down) variables are going -1 and to start go down we need clicking down again few times.

Comment: well, then you need to limit this, like adding if(targetOptTop==0){targetOptTop=1;return;} right after you decrement targetOptTop--

Comment: Ok, I got the main idea and now remember that have to change var before use it in class changing. Thanks a lot ))